# How to replace values in text file?

Tags: python, file

I have a settings file which is called test.py. In this file I have to replace some `float`, `int`, `string` values. eg: `ORDER_PAIRS = 0.01` is a `float` that i can replace with another `float` value. And `ORDER_CONTENT = "some string"` is a `string` value. I need to read these values and replace them with new values, then overwrite the file. Like edit a settings file.

Example: I need to change `ORDER_PAIRS = 0.01` to `ORDER_PAIRS = 0.03` or `ORDER_CONTENT = "some string"` to `ORDER_CONTENT = "some new string"`.

Here is my code.

```
FileName = "test.py"

# Open file and replace line
with open(FileName) as f:
    updatedString = f.read().replace("ORDER_PAIRS = old value", "ORDER_PAIRS = " + new value)

# Write updated string to file
with open(FileName, "w") as f:
    f.write(updatedString)
```

How can I change certain values?

Comment: I want to replace the old value with new value, but i shouldnt hardcode the old value, it should read the old value and replace it with the new one. Like ORDER_PAIRS = x (the old value) should be replaced what i wanted.

Comment: In that case, just _create_ the first string argument that's used in the call to `replace()` and put the desired old value you want in it (instead of hardcoding it).

Comment: The problem it is, how can i read the old value eg: ORDER_PAIRS = X the x value int or float sometimes.But other values can be string too, like ORDER_URL = "some string" i have to read all that different values and replace to the new.

Comment: mrdabanli: That's also doable — just sounds like multiple replaces would need to be done. I suggest you [edit] your question again and try to describe what you want to do better and show your latest attempts at doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and works fine on Python 3.7.3

```
import os
with open('newfile.txt','w') as outfile: #file to write, you can then rename your file
    with open('pytest.txt', 'r') as file: #contains your records
        a=file.read()
        if "ORDER_PAIRS = 11" in a:
            #print (a)
            b=a.replace('ORDER_PAIRS = 11','ORDER_PAIRS = 10')
            #print (b)
            outfile.write(b)
        else:
            outfile.write(a)
os.rename('pytest.txt','pytest.txt.bkp') # taking backup of old file
os.rename('newfile.txt','pytest.txt') #renaming new file back to old file
```

Comment: Is possible to open two files with a single `with`
`with open(...) as a, open (...) as b` :)

Comment: This may work, but doing it shouldn't be necessary.